# How to access an object's text on click in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an object which contains some details and in HTML I have three hyperlinks: first, second and both. I want it so that when I click on the hyperlinks I can match the object's text and append it on the div.

```
<head>
   <style>
      .text { border:solid 1px #F00; height:30px;}
   </style>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var myDate= {
        'first':'hi i am first object',
        'second':'hi i am second object'
      }
      $(function (){
        $('.text').text()
      })
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="text"></div>
   <a href="#">first</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">second</a>
   <a href="#">both</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Hint: [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/vVmPW/

Comment: Thanks for replying, your answer is work for me. Could you please tell me how function is knowing to show match value

Comment: can we store objects in loop. for example myDate[i]

Answer (score 1):

You have to use .click()

http://jsfiddle.net/nsjithin/2jTAy/1/